# CodeIgniter ajax post only working once

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Hello I'm trying to delete a row in the database using ajax post but the problem is that the row gets deleted only once per page load. The row get detach from the HTML DOM everything I press the delete button, but the database only deletes one record. I want to delete therecord in the database every time I press the delete button. How can I achieve this ?

My view

```
<tbody id="tbody"><?php
    $count = 1;
    foreach($rows as $row):?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$count?></td>
            <td><a href="basic_table.html#">
                <?=$row->FirstName." ".$row->LastName?></a>
            </td>                        
            <td class="hidden-phone"><?=$row->Email?></td>
            <td><?=$row->Password?></td>
            <td><span class="label label-warning label-mini">
                <?=date("m/d/Y", strtotime($row->Created))?></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs">
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                </button>
                <button id="delete" data-id="<?=$row->id?>" 
                    data-url="<?=base_url()?>" class="btn btn-danger 
                    btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash-o "></i>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr><?php
        $count++;
    endforeach?>
</tbody>
```

script

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#tbody").on('click','#delete', function()
{
    var id = $("#delete").data("id");
    var url = $("#delete").data("url");

    $.post(url + "users/delete", { id : id, cache: false } , function()
    {

    },"json");

    $(this).closest('tr').detach();
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give the codeigniter controller script

You must change to anchor tag and add preventDefault() to prevent reloading page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tbody").on('click','#delete', function(e){
        //You must add e.preventDefault() to avoid reloading page
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $("#delete").data("id");
        var url = $("#delete").data("url");

        $.post(url + "users/delete", { id : id, cache: false } , function(){
        },"json");

        $(this).closest('tr').detach();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks you so much you solved my problem. Sorry the reason I didn't posted the controller or the model is because i know my logic there is ok. thanks again